# ACE Client License on Trial Edition

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have downloaded and installed trial edition of WS7 and ACE Management server pack in my lab. I created a package and try to use the package on one of my test machine. It prompts me to enter the ACE Client license for the player. I have not get any client license for this. Where can i get this?
Please help me on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into your account on vmware.com, look at your trial licenses, it'll be listed there.